# Database function dependency

Tags: database, database-normalization

I have few questions about functional dependency.

First, there are students and courses in school, each student can enroll in many courses. Each course has many students. So how to use functional dependency to represent this? 
`students -> courses, courses -> students`?

And if `F = {A -> BCD, CD->A}`, is this equivalent to `{CD->A, A->B}`? or is there any simple form for `F`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1. You can't. You put student and course into one relation:

```
 student | course 
---------------------
 John    | Databases
 Wolf    | Algorithms
 Wolf    | Databases
 John    | Art
```

You have no (nontrivial) functional dependencies here. Student does not determine the course (because he may attend many). Course does not determine the student (because there are many students in a course). The pair (student, course) is key in this relation. In fact, having no functional dependencies tells you that there is many-to-many association between students and courses.

Ad 2. They aren't equivalent. You can derive the latter from F but you can't derive F from {CD->A, A->B}. You can't derive the functional dependency A -> BCD.

You might read [my (very informal) article on functional dependencies](http://vertabelo.com/blog/functional-dependencies).